# Making sure entries only enter once into database using PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am validating a form using javascript and I need the values in there to be entered into a database and for that I am using PHP. However, if you use if(isset ) then even if the form is invalid and the values are wrong, the wrong data will be entered into the database. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Yes there is - if the values are invalid - don't put them in DB

Comment: Could you provide your client and your server side code?

Comment: Use more conditions in `if` statement.

Comment: but then i have to revalidate in PHP

Comment: @faraday You should validate in PHP whether or not you're validating in JavaScript. Any decent developer tools package can mess with JS and/or form values.

Comment: @faraday please add your php and javascript form validation code.

Comment: Js validation is only for user comfort. You should not trust it. Make 2 way validation from client and server side.